# Selecting Video from Camera Roll

Tags: ios, swift

I have no idea how to select a video from the camera roll using Swift in iOS. I am making an instagram app clone and I want users to only be able to select videos from their camera roll.

I have searched this question on google and only found tutorials explaining how to select images from the camera roll.

Comment: `UIImagePickerController`. Please do some basic research. Try something. Update your question with what you have tried/researched and clearly explain where you are having an issue.

Comment: There are lots of material for this on the internet

Comment: I have not found anything. I searched "Selecting videos from camera roll" and only found tutorials on how to select images from the camera roll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
func getMovie() {
    let selecionadorDeFoto = UIImagePickerController()
    selecionadorDeFoto.delegate = self

    selecionadorDeFoto.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]

    selecionadorDeFoto.allowsEditing = false

    selecionadorDeFoto.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(selecionadorDeFoto, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add a framework do be able to work with the kUTTypeMovie? I tried using the code you replied to me with, but I got an error saying, "Use of unresolved identifier "kUTTypeMovie"

Comment: Yes. `import MobileCoreServices`

Comment: An error for this line:  selecionadorDeFoto.delegate = self says: "Cannot assign value of type 'ViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?' even after I imported that framework.

Comment: Your class need to inherit from UIPickerControllerDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: I got it working. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem. Please check the answer.